# find a regular expression and FA that each define L1 ∩ L2

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions

from the following pairs I am trying to find a `regular expression` and `FA` that each define `L1 ∩ L2`...How would I do this ?

L1 is `(ab*)*` and L2 is `b(a+b)*`

this is what I have...I am on the right track here or am I completely wrong ?

[image]

Comment: crosspost with http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/find-a-regular-expression-and-fa-that-each-define-l-1-cap-l-2

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Each word of $L_1 = (\mathtt{ab}^*)^*$ starts with $\mathtt{a}$ or is empty.
- All words of $L_2 = \mathtt{b}(\mathtt{a}+\mathtt{b})^*$ start with $\mathtt{b}$ and are non-empty.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: do I have to do a compliment here ? meaning take anywhere you have a plus , get rid of it and anywhere you didn't have a plus add one in

Comment: @Ris Indeed, one is the complement of the other. But what you suggest (replacing concatenation with union and vice versa) does not give you the complement of the language.